# ReactJS - Como chamar o estado de um input para outra Classe

Tags: javascript, react, framework, componentes

belezinha?

Bom sou leigo no ReactJS, estou aprendendo e ao mesmo tempo utilizando para trabalho e assim possuo o seguinte problema:

Tenho um checkbox que se estiver assinalado um botão de outro componente deve ficar disabled... A pergunta é, como eu faço isso?
OBS: Essa demanda é uma continuação de uma outra empresa ou seja eu tenho mais ou menos isso já feito..

Arquivo/Caminho: *RAIZ/Climb-web/src/screens_dashboard/professional.js

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.master } onChange={ this.toggleMaster } />
```

E tenho o botão nesse caminho: *RAIZ/landing_page/src/container/search.js

```html
<Button color="info" className="text-uppercase" >Sessão gratuita</Button>
```

Pelo que vi fazendo alguns testes, tentei dar um import no caminho e ele não deixa passar da paste Src.

Agradeço se puderem me ajudar.

[image: Minhas pastas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luis, vai depender de onde o checkbox e o botão estiverem, vou explicar...
Se ambos pertencerem ao mesmo componente você poderá controlar o `disabled` através de uma variável de estado. Veja um exemplo bem simples:

```
<button disabled={!this.state.isActive}>Meu Botao</button>
<input type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => this.handleCheck(event)} />

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isActive: false
    };
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
}

handleCheck(event) {
    isActive = event.target.checked;
    this.setState({ isActive: !isActive });
}
```

Agora se o checkbox e o button estiverem em componentes distintos você precisará adotar um meio de efetuar uma comunicação entre os componentes para chegar neste resultado. Uma sugestão ([exemplo](https://medium.com/coding-stuff/pubsub-for-communicating-between-react-components-999159d59a77) de utilização) é utilizar o [pubsubjs](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) mas há outras formas.

Utilizando o pubsubjs você emitirá um valor quando o checkbox for alterado. Na outra ponta (outro componente onde o botão está) você passará a "ouvir" os valores emitidos. Quando um valor for emitido você poderá habilitar ou desabilitar seu botão:

```
// No componente do checkbox:
handleCheck(event) {
    isActive = event.target.checked;

    // Emite o valor do checkbox para quem estiver inscrito no canal "estadoDoBotao"
    PubSub.publish('estadoDoBotao', isActive);
}

// No outro componente, onde o botão está:
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isActive: false };

    // Toda vez que um valor for emitido:
    PubSub.subscribe('estadoDoBotao', (msg, data) => {
        this.setState({ isActive: data });
    }.bind(this));
}
```